# hslogger & Duplicate Log Lines

Tags: haskell

I've configured logging like so:

```
import System.Environment
import System.Log.Logger
import System.Log.Handler (setFormatter)
import System.Log.Handler.Simple (streamHandler)
import System.Log.Formatter
import System.IO (getLine, stdout)
main = do
stdOutHandler <- streamHandler stdout DEBUG >>= \lh -> return $
            setFormatter lh (simpleLogFormatter "[$time : $loggername : $prio] $msg")
  updateGlobalLogger "Linker" (setLevel DEBUG . setHandlers [stdOutHandler])
  infoM "Linker" "Hello world!"
```

Unfortunately, every time I use `infoM` (or any logging function), I get duplicate lines, e.g.

```
infoM "Linker" "hi there"
```

produces:

```
hi there
[2016-12-05 20:23:10 GMT : Linker : INFO] hi there
```

I thought `setHandlers` removed other handlers first.

I want just the lines that are formatted, not the "normal" format ala `putStrLn` etc.

Comment: Could you please provide smallest complete code example? From what you wrote I don't see any reasons why it shouldn't work.

Comment: Yep. Updated with a complete example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found error in your program. Actually, it was in your first code, I just didn't pay enough attention to it :(

All you need is to replace logger name with [rootLoggerName](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hslogger-1.2.10/docs/System-Log-Logger.html#v:rootLoggerName) in

```
updateGlobalLogger "Linker"
```

to

```
updateGlobalLogger rootLoggerName
```

This did the trick for me. I don't know what happens when you're not initializing with root logger but now it will at least work.

Also, if you're using `stack` and don't mind using `github` projects then you may wish to consider using our logging library (it is not currently on hackage) which is a wrapper around `hslogger` which adds some juice to it (like coloured logger names and more):

https://github.com/serokell/log-warper

[image: Colored logging]

Comment: Hmmm, but the reason I'm using `"Linker"` in the logger name is because I am logging to that specific logger each time. What's the point of logger names if root is always the one used? I thought I had to configure them by-name?

Comment: @atc Point of logger names is that `hslogger` uses hierarchy of loggers. All loggers should be children of `rootLoggerName`. For example `"Linker.Child"` is a child of logger with name `"Linker"` and `"Linker"` is a child of `""` which is `rootLoggerName`. By default all children inherits `Priority` from their parent. Consider next code: http://lpaste.net/6216398766442807296 . You won't see `"Hallo 2"` message. So you should initialize _root_ and only then initialize all your subloggers.

Comment: Makes sense! I understood the hierarchy element just hadn't expected that setting a child would end up with duplicates, but of course the `setHandlers` is applied to the child and _not_ the root logger, hence the duplication. Thanks!