# Printing Timestamps while Debugging in Haskell

Tags: haskell, io, bind

I'm still learning Haskell and debugging some functions, and usually have a timestamp function to get a sense of when certain operations start and stop:

```
doSomeAction :: String -> IO ()
doSomeAction arg1 = do
  putStrLn =<< makeTime
  theThingthatTakesAwhile arg1
  putStrLn =<< makeTime
  where
    makeTime = (formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%Y%m%d%H%M%S") <$> getZonedTime
```

Is my `=<<` and `where` clause containing an `<$>` a reasonable way to interact with the IO around `getZonedTime`?

```
λ> :t getZonedTime
getZonedTime :: IO ZonedTime
```

Or is this misleading to me or the reader or non-idiomatic?

Output is:

```
20170114152312
Doing some long function....
20170114152336
```

Which is exactly what I want to see---it tells me what I need.  Just seems odd to `putStrLn =<< something` to get that effect.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is perfectly fine. Any programmer fluent in Haskell should understand it quickly.

In my own style, though, I tend to prefer `let` in `do` blocks:

```
doSomeAction :: String -> IO ()
doSomeAction arg1 = do
  let makeTime = formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%Y%m%d%H%M%S" <$> getZonedTime
  putStrLn =<< makeTime
  theThingthatTakesAwhile arg1
  putStrLn =<< makeTime
```

or possibly some variation of

```
doSomeAction :: String -> IO ()
doSomeAction arg1 = do
  let printTime = putStrLn . formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%Y%m%d%H%M%S" =<< getZonedTime
  printTime
  theThingthatTakesAwhile arg1
  printTime
```

but again, It's only a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

You can do better if you use some logging library. For example [`hslogger`](https://www.stackage.org/lts-7.15/package/hslogger-1.2.10). It can print messages with timestamps. You can see examples of usages under this questions: [hslogger & Duplicate Log Lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40982746/hslogger-duplicate-log-lines/40995265#40995265)

**UPD:** *Example with logging timestamps*

Here is complete example of module with initialization of logging:

```
import           Control.Concurrent        (threadDelay)
import           System.IO                 (stdout)
import           System.Log.Formatter      (simpleLogFormatter)
import           System.Log.Handler        (setFormatter)
import           System.Log.Handler.Simple (streamHandler)
import           System.Log.Logger         (Priority (DEBUG), debugM, rootLoggerName,
                                            setHandlers, setLevel, updateGlobalLogger)

initLogging :: IO ()
initLogging = do
    stdOutHandler <- streamHandler stdout DEBUG >>= \lh -> return $
            setFormatter lh (simpleLogFormatter "[$loggername:$time] $msg")
    updateGlobalLogger rootLoggerName (setLevel DEBUG . setHandlers [stdOutHandler])

doSomeAction :: String -> IO ()
doSomeAction arg1 = do
    debugM "someAction" "before long thing"
    theThingThatTakesAWhile arg1
    debugM "someAction" "after long thing"

theThingThatTakesAWhile :: String -> IO ()
theThingThatTakesAWhile arg = threadDelay (3 * 10^(6 :: Int)) >> putStrLn arg

main :: IO ()
main = do
    initLogging
    doSomeAction "some long action"
```

And the output is:

```
[someAction:2017-01-16 17:19:49 MSK] before long thing
some long action
[someAction:2017-01-16 17:19:52 MSK] after long thing
```

If you want time to be printed as timestamps (only seconds) than you can use [`tfLogFormatter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hslogger-1.2.10/docs/System-Log-Formatter.html#v:tfLogFormatter) function to specify exact format of your message.

Comment: Can you provide an example to help me understand how to declare the initialization outside of my function so I can easily call `updateGlobalLogger rootLoggerName` inside?

Comment: @Mittenchops I've updated answer with example of logging initialization.