# Optional parameters along with a case statement

Tags: haskell, option-type

I learned about hslogger [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41655218/printing-timestamps-while-debugging-in-haskell).

```
initLogging :: Priority -> IO ()
initLogging level = do
    stdOutHandler <- streamHandler stdout level >>= \lh -> return $
            setFormatter lh (simpleLogFormatter "[$prio:$loggername:$time] $msg")
    updateGlobalLogger rootLoggerName (setLevel level . setHandlers [stdOutHandler])
```

I'd like to make a "quicklog" function that just requires less typing to use for debugging: if logtype is specified as "I", will use `infoM`, and if specified as "D", will use `debugM`, etc., and defaults to `INFO` if no loglevel is specified.

I can make a version that kind of does what I need:

```
qLog :: String -> String -> IO ()
qLog l msg = log' "" msg where
  log' "I" msg = infoM "" msg
  log' "D" msg = debugM "" msg
  log' "E" msg = errorM "" msg
  log' "W" msg = warningM "" msg
  log' _ msg = infoM "" msg
```

And this works:

```
λ> qlog "D" "Thing!"
[DEBUG::2017-01-18 20:38:19 EST] Thing!

λ> qlog "I" "Thing!"
[INFO::2017-01-18 20:38:19 EST] Thing!
```

But I can not get it to work to choose infoM if no level is specified, a la:

```
λ> qlog "Thing!"
[INFO::2017-01-18 20:38:19 EST] Thing!
```

This simply fails, expecting "Thing!" is the optional loglevel, rather than the msg argument.  I believe this requires a Maybe to convey that the first argument may not exist at all, but can't seem to get it right.  Here are my attempts:

```
qLog2 :: Maybe String -> String -> IO ()
qLog2 l msg = case l msg of
     (Just "D") msg -> debugM "" msg
     (Just "I") msg -> infoM "" msg
     Nothing  msg -> infoM "" msg
```

Or

```
qLog3 :: Maybe String -> String -> IO ()
qLog3 l msg 
  | Just "D" msg = debugM "" msg
  | Just "I" msg = infoM "" msg
  | Nothing  msg = infoM "" msg
```

I can't seem to phrase the combination of how to maybe in the type declaration + either `case` or `guard` sufficiently.

UPDATE 1

```
qLog4 "D" msg = debugM "" msg
qLog4 "I" msg = infoM "" msg
qLog4 msg  = infoM "" msg
```

Gives me:

```
Equations for ‘qLog4’ have different numbers of arguments
```

UPDATE 2:

Abandoning cases while I figure out the optional argument part via [here](http://www.haskellforall.com/2015/06/optional-args-100-optional-function.html)

```
import Data.Optional

newtype LogLevel = LogLevel { getLogLevel :: Char } 

qLog' :: Char -> String -> IO ()
qLog' "I" msg = infoM "" msg
qLog' "D" msg = debugM "" msg
qLog' "W" msg = warningM "" msg
qLog' "E" msg = errorM "" msg
qLog' _ msg = infoM "" msg

qLog5 :: (Optional LogLevel) -> String -> IO ()
qLog5 (Specific l) msg = qLog' (getLogLevel l) msg 
qLog5 (Default) msg = qLog' "I" msg


<interactive>:251:7-9: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Char’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
    • In the pattern: "
```

Comment: Your second last variant is closest. You just need to have `l` and `msg` be in a tuple and pattern match against that (a `case` only branches based on _one_ expression). That said, why not get rid of the `case` altogether and just have multiple variants?

Comment: @Alec, I tried that in the update, but the compiler complained about multiple arguments, which is the part I'm after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your issue correct, then you can do like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

qlog :: LogResult a => a
qlog = log' []

class LogResult a where
    log' :: [LogArg] -> a

class IsLogArgument a where
    toLogArg :: a -> LogArg

data LogArg = LogLevel LogLevel
            | LogMessage String

data LogLevel = D | I | W | E

instance IsLogArgument LogLevel where
    toLogArg = LogLevel

instance (a ~ Char) => IsLogArgument [a] where
    toLogArg = LogMessage

instance (IsLogArgument arg, LogResult result) => LogResult (arg -> result) where
    log' args arg = log' ((toLogArg arg) : args)

instance (a ~ ()) => LogResult (IO a) where
    log' args = tell "" msg
      where
        tell = case level of
                D -> debugM
                I -> infoM
                W -> warningM
                E -> errorM
        level = fromMaybe I $ look logLevel
        msg   = fromMaybe "No message" $ look logMessage

        logLevel (LogLevel x) = Just x
        logLevel _            = Nothing

        logMessage (LogMessage x) = Just x
        logMessage _              = Nothing

        look = listToMaybe . catMaybes . flip map args
```

And:

```
λ> qlog D "Thing!"
[DEBUG::2017-01-18 20:38:19 EST] Thing!

λ> qlog "Thing!"
[INFO::2017-01-18 20:38:19 EST] Thing!
```

Comment: Wow!  That is an awful lot of code for an optional argument.

Comment: Yes, but you can do more. For example, you can simply add an optional LogName and you free from arguments order.

Answer (score 3):

A fixed version of `qLog2` would be

```
qLog2 :: Maybe String -> String -> IO ()
qLog2 l msg =
  case l of
    Just "D" -> debugM "" msg
    Just "I" -> infoM "" msg
    Nothing  -> infoM "" msg
```

If you were going to overload `qlog` to take an optional parameter for the level you'd need to use a typeclass. This function would be annoying to use. It would be ambiguous when you write `qlog "I"` if you expected this to have type `String -> IO ()` or `IO ()`. Maybe you created a log function for the info level, or maybe you were logging the message "I"

Comment: I understand the concern theoretically, but I'm using this for debugging messages, so it will be easy to avoid including `qlog "I"` in my debugs.

Comment: It's not something you can ignore. It's the same problem if you had `qlog "A Log Message"`. It's ambiguous (without additional context) if that's a log message or a debug level. You only get to consider the types when making this distinction. The values don't matter.

Comment: I guess.  But I can solve that with Char is a different type than [Char], right?  If I'm not going to make 1 character debug messages--because that's not useful for debugging--there won't actually be any ambiguity given the intended application.

Answer (score 3):

You only need to do case analysis on the `l` argument:

```
qLog :: Maybe String -> String -> IO ()
qLog l msg = case l of
    Just "D" -> debugM "" msg
    Just "I" -> infoM "" msg
    -- etc.
    Nothing  -> infoM "" msg
```

(If you actually needed to do case analysis on `msg` as well, you might do it through a tuple -- `case (l, msg) of` -- as Alec suggests, or just replace the case statement with multiple equations.)

---

Unrelated suggestions: rather than strings, you can use a custom type to represent your log levels. That both makes things clearer and eliminates the risk of passing `"G"` or `"foobar"` as a log level.

```
-- Feel free to use less terse names.
data LogLevel = D | I | W | E
    deriving (Eq, Show)

qLog :: Maybe LogLevel -> String -> IO ()
qLog l msg = case l of
    Just D -> debugM "" msg
    Just I -> infoM "" msg
    Just W -> warningM "" msg
    Just E -> errorM "" msg
    Nothing -> infoM "" msg
```

You can also factor out a good part of the repetitiveness:

```
-- I added a few superflous parentheses to emphasise what is going on.
qLog :: Maybe LogLevel -> String -> IO ()
qLog ml msg = case ml of
     Just l -> (fLog l) "" msg
     Nothing -> infoM "" msg
     where
     fLog :: LogLevel -> (String -> String -> IO ())
     fLog l = case l of
         D -> debugM
         I -> infoM
         W -> warningM
         E -> errorM
```

Or, using the `maybe` to neatly eliminate the maybe-ness:

```
GHCi> :t maybe
maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b
```

```
-- There are also some superflous parentheses here.
qLog :: Maybe LogLevel -> String -> IO ()
qLog ml msg = (maybe infoM fLog ml) "" msg
     where
     fLog :: LogLevel -> (String -> String -> IO ())
     fLog l = case l of
         D -> debugM
         I -> infoM
         W -> warningM
         E -> errorM
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, when I try omitting the optional argument, I get: `λ> qLog "test"

    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Maybe String’
                  with actual type ‘[Char]’
`

Comment: @Mittenchops That's because you still need to provide a `Maybe String` argument, even if it is a `Nothing`. If you want to omit it entirely, either leave out the `Maybe` and define a separate function that doesn't take the log level at all (eg. `qLogDef :: LogLevel -> String -> IO (); qLogDef = qLog I`) or use the varargs trick in freestyle's answer.

Comment: (Note that I mistyped the signature of `qLogDef` in the comment above -- it should be `qLogDef :: String -> IO ()`.)